# Does plink support GSSAPI?

Tags: putty, kerberos, plink

Does **plink** support GSSAPI? I know putty itself does and enabling GSSAPI works fine with putty, but for some reason it is not working with plink. I was under impression that plink would work the same.

The problem I'm having is that a script using plink all of the sudden was reported not to work. Indeed it asks for password, which it previously did not. So I've investigated this problem and have tried asking the IT center if they used to have some other key based authentication but they were not than helpful. So my question is as follows:

1. If plink does support GSSAPI then why does not my plink not work? And what can I possibly do about this? Is it something that is a known problem/limitation?
2. If putty does not support GSSAPI, and the system is not running pageant what other authentication option could have been used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some meditation I eventually came up with the answer. The default settings have changed so that GSSAPI is turned off. To fix this problem:

1. Open putty
2. Under category Connection -> SSH -> Auth -> GSSAPI enable:

   Attempt GSSAPI authentication
3. Save as Default Settings in the Sessions Category.

Now it works.